# How to find which row was edited using X-editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

I m using http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable X-editable plugin for making  some columns editable in my table. But how should I proceed, so that I can know which row was edited . I mean say there is Student table (Rollno, Name, Address) . So, If I update any Name in any row .Then , how will I get the roll no  whose name was updated . And how to call the Editable method.
For example ,

$('what to write here').editable({});

Answer (score 0):

Use save event

```
    $('.student').on('save', function(e, params) {
        alert('Saved value: ' + params.newValue);
        console.log('Student saved: ' + e);
    });
```

(console log is watchable with Chrome's console and Firefox's firebug).

Answer (score -1):

You can use this if each row is related to a different ID:

```
$("#tableID tbody").delegate("tr", "click", function() {cell=(this.cells[i].innerText);})
```